# How to write test case for below java code

Tags: java, junit

```
public class CollectionUtils {
    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> createMap(Iterable<V> values, Function<V, K> keyFunction, boolean skipNullKeys) {
        Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (V value : values) {
            K key = keyFunction.apply(value);
            if (key != null || !skipNullKeys) {
                map.put(key, value);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Comment: You have a `Function` from a value to a key. Do you know that you will overwrite the map's value if this function results a key twice?

Answer (score 1):

I would use small and simple data, e. g.

```
List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(1, null);
Function<Integer, String> toKey = String::valueOf;
Map<String, Integer> withNull = createMap(values, toKey, false);
Map<String, Integer> noNull = createMap(values, toKey, true);
```

Then you can test with `Map#size`, `Map#containsKey` (needed for `null`-key) and `...get("1").equals(1)`.

But as I mentioned in the comment, if your function may result in the same key for different values you only have the last value, e. g. `Function<Integer, Integer> toKey = i -> i%2` will only procude `0` or `1` as a key (and a `NullPointerException` for `null`-values) so `List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(1, 3)` will produce a `Map` with only one entry `"1" -> 3`.